# Demarcating transactions in services or JPARepositories

Tags: java, spring, jpa

According to  [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions) jpa repositories instances are transactional, but in other bibliography says that transactions should be declared in the service layer. What is the better approach?

Comment: Default methods of Spring Data JPA repositories are transactional, any custom method that you may add must be explicitly annotated as Transactional. Transaction propagation is a different subject and different propagation types and there different recommendations for their use. i.e one is  REQUIRES_NEW for the service layer, MANDATORY for the DAOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a single JPA repository method is executed transactionally, often it is required to execute transactions including various JPA repository method calls.

Consider the classic approach of transferring an amount from one account to another. It is necessary to rollback if an error occurs at any stage during the transfer. Therefore the entire (service) method is `@Transactional`:

```
@Transactional
public void transfer(Account a, Account b, int amount) {
    a.reduce(amount);
    b.add(amount),
    accountRepository.save(a);
    accountRepository.save(b);
}
```

Here, even an error on saving account b won't alter the persisted state of account a, because everything in the `transfer` method is rolled back.

To enable transaction management in Spring, use `@EnableTransactionManagement` on a Java `@Configuration` class or `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in case of XML configuration.